# How can I parse a JSON Array from API with GSON using Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

.Hi!

This is the API response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Facebook"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Angry Birds"
    }
]
```

This is my Retrofit API declaration:

```
  @GET("/api/apps")
  suspend fun getApps(): Response<AppList<App>>
```

These are my App and AppList classes:

```
class App(

    var id: Number,
    var name: String

    ) : Serializable
```

---

```
class AppList<App>(list: List<App>)
```

This is how I call the API:

```
 val response: Response<AppList<App>> = API.callBackend().getApplications()
```

And this is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

How can I parse an array with GSON? What am I missing here?

**E D I T:**

If I change all of my `AppList<App>` to `List<App>` I got no `IllegalException` but my App instances remain absolutely empty, meaning the `id` and `name` are both **null**.

Comment: what is the point of `AppList<T>` ? why you think that serializer will know that this is array ? why didn't you use just `List<App>` ?

Comment: Is that json correctly formatted? I don't see any opening braces (nor closing ones either). That may explain the error message. It does not find a BEGIN_OBJECT ( { ) but a BEGIN_ARRAY ( [ ).

Answer (score 0):

The method signature should be as below:

```
interface ApiService {
   @GET("/api/apps")
   suspend fun getApps(): List<App>
}
```

The `App` class should be as below:

```
data class App(val id: Long, val name: String)
```

Invoke the API like this:

```
class AppRepository(private val api: ApiService) {
    suspend fun getApps() {
        withContext(Dispaatchers.IO) {
            val apps = api.getApps();
            // perform operation with apps obtained from API
        }
     }
}
```

Because it's a suspend function, you don't need to wrap the return type with response objects like `Response`, Retrofit is smart enough to identify and deserialise the type. If there are any errors, it'll throw an exception instead of returning an error response.

The reason of the error is that your `AppList` class is looking for a `list` array in your response object. With your current `AppList` class, your response would have to look as below in order to deserialise successfully. Now you understand why the error message `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY` make sense.

```
{
   "list": [
    
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Facebook"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Angry Birds"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Selvin I made the edit

Answer (score 0):

Just make the below changes to your Interface and see if it works or not.

```
 @GET("/api/apps")
  suspend fun getApps(): Response<ArrayList<App>>
```

Change your app class like below.

```
   data class App(
        @SerializedName("id")
        var id: Number,
        @SerializedName("name")
        var name: String
        ): Serializable
```

Comment: Sadly, no......

Comment: are you using a debug app build right? @AdamVarhegyi

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a JSON array from an API using Gson and Retrofit by making a few adjustments to your code. Here's how you can do it:

1. Update your Retrofit API declaration:

```kotlin
@GET("/api/apps")
suspend fun getApps(): Response<List<App>>
```

This change tells Retrofit to expect a JSON array as a response.

2. Modify your `AppList` class. It's not necessary to create a custom `AppList` class; you can directly use a `List<App>` as the response type.
3. Ensure that your `App` class has a no-argument constructor and properly named fields for Gson to map the JSON to the object. You can use annotations to specify the JSON names if they don't match exactly:

```kotlin
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class App(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,

    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String
)
```

With these changes, your Retrofit service interface, `App` class, and the API call should work correctly. Here's how you can call the API:

```kotlin
try {
    val response: Response<List<App>> = API.callBackend().getApps()

    if (response.isSuccessful) {
        val apps: List<App>? = response.body()
        if (apps != null) {
            for (app in apps) {
                // Handle each app here
                println("App ID: ${app.id}, Name: ${app.name}")
            }
        } else {
            // Handle null response
        }
    } else {
        // Handle the error response
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // Handle exceptions
}
```

With these changes, Gson should correctly parse the JSON array response into a list of `App` objects.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Do it exactly like this, doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Don't forget this point :
Modify your AppList class. It's not necessary to create a custom AppList class; you can directly use a List<App> as the response type.

Comment: Your App class seems fine, but you should modify your AppList class to correctly handle the list of App objects. Remove the type parameter from AppList, and it should look like this:

```kotlin
class AppList(
    val list: List<App>
)
```

Alternatively, you can directly use a `List<App>` as the response type, eliminating the need for the custom AppList class. After making these changes, your Retrofit service interface should look like this:

```kotlin
@GET("/api/apps")
suspend fun getApps(): Response<List<App>>
```